# Change some translation during runtime

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I have an AngularJS Application, which is available in 3 Languages and it uses .json files to load all the language key value pairs.

However I want to dynamically change some of the key value pairs during runtime.

So for example I have "ORDER.HEADING" to be "Heading" by default. And if the user does something specific it should be "Different Heading".

How do I do that? I can't access the translateProvider Service in a controller and the $translate service doesn't seem to have a method which can update key value pairs...

Comment: never used angular-translate but changing key value at runtime doesn't seem the best solution, use two different key like ORDERD.HEADING and ORDER.HEADING.SPECIAL and change the binding at runtime ... post your code or a jsfiddle for more help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not update the json file and its key/value paris on runtime.
I suggest you do the following:

In your template call a function to retrieve your key:

```
<h1>{{ $ctrl.getI18nHeadingKey() | translate }}</h1>
```

Inside your controller:

```
this.someCondition = false;

getI18nHeadingKey() {
  return this.someCondition ? 'YOUR_TRANSLATION_KEY_IF_IT_IS_TRUE' : 'YOUR_TRANSLATION_KEY_IF_IT_IS_FALSE';
}
```

Make sure to have both keys added and translated inside your json files, just as you did with all your other translations.
The given example can be expanded in case you have more than one condition of course. Just return the translation key you want in your template for the given condition.